# find div within parent div by parent div class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a situation with two divs, one parent div which has proper classes and another div inside the parent div which doesn't have any class but on a jquery event from the parent div I want to assign a class to the inner div. 
This is how the structure looks:

```
<div class="noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower">
    <div class="">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any advice how to get to the inner div and assign a class by calling the parent div with jquery?

Comment: jQuery has relatively good API documentation. Make use of it! http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/, http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Do you want to add the same class? Or did you want to add a completly different class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `attr-elem` selector like

```
$('.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower > div[class=""]').addClass('whatever');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p2A4Q/)

If you don't want to add class with jQuery and simply want to target those elements than only CSS would suffice as well..

```
.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower > div[class=""] {
    /* Targets those div elements which has empty class attribute */
}
```

Explanation : The selector selects all the `div` elements with empty `class` attribute which are direct child to element having both the classes i.e `.noUi-handle` and `.noUi-handle-lower`

Answer (score 0):

Try `.find`. In conjunction with `$(this)` it will only look for child elements on that event.

```
function pizzaToppings() {
   $(this).find('div').addClass('mushrooms');
}

$('.noUi-handle').on('click', pizzaToppings);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/3Vf9t/)